# Current Transformer Transformation Ratio Variation

Tags: transformer

Lately I have been working on Energy Analyzers for Generators. I have a slight problem working with CTs.

I ran an experiment with 5 CTs rated at 2.4VA(60/5) of same manufacture with burden resistor of 0.07ohm and subject them to load 5A-50A with step size of 5A.

I found that the curve(R vs I) remains somewhat flat from 27A and onwards while it starts to climb below 27A. Also the ratio does not remain 12 for all CTs even in flat region.

I am using CS5463 from Cirrus Logic for Energy Measurement. It allows max 250mV peak signal for current and voltage measurement. The IC reads correct Current Values up till 21A with maximum error of 1.7% while the error increased to 2% below 21A. Is this behaviour of CT normal?

I repeated the same process on next day to check repeatablity but the error increased to 5% at 26A.

If same manufacture CTs have different transformation ratios and can have drift in their characteristics over a day, how can I get around this problem?

Comment: Link the data sheet and show your results numerically. How can anyone analyse what you are saying without numbers and a part?

Comment: I also note that you have not formally accepted any answers to your previous questions - do you realize that this ought to be considered?

Comment: My apologies if did not responded to previous answers. I shall post the numerical results.

Answer (score 1):

One part of your problem jumps out immediately.

> "and subject them to load 5A-50A". . . . "I am using CS5463 from Cirrus Logic for Energy Measurement. It allows max 250mV peak signal for current and voltage measurement. The IC reads correct Current Values up till 21A"

From the data sheet :   “With a 10x gain on the voltage and current channel the maximum input signal is 250 mVP”

The maximum current that your system can measure is (per specification) is 30.3 amps RMS.

\$ .250/.07 = 3.57 A_p\$

\$ 3.57 A_p * (60/5) = 42.85 A_p\$

\$42.85 A_p * .707 = 30.3 Amps RMS\$

Any data taken where current is greater than 30.3 Amps RMS will be invalid.

Also, if your load peak current is higher than 42.85 amps, measurement will be invalid.

You point out that your measurements seem to diverge at around 27 amps, which is near the 30 amps calculated.  Then later you mention 21 amps as the point where measurements seem to diverge.

Without further information on tolerances on your .07 ohm resistor and current transformers, and schematic on your exact circuit, I cannot help further.

Comment: Thank you Marla. I have now got a current sense resistor of 12mohm value. I shall post the numerical results for the new resistor. But now I plan to use 50x gain of IC as 10x gain will be too low for 12mohm resistor. This will produce 60mV RMS for 5A RMS current. I plan to use a voltage divider, to reduce 60mV to 30mV RMS, with resistances in range of mega ohm  so that most current still passes through current sense resistor. I will post the schematic as well.